# PLSQL %NOTFOUND Simple test case not working as expected

Tags: plsql

I'm an Oracle noobie, playing when I got an unexpected result:

The following snippet, which you should be able to run...

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c_dual1 IS SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 1=1;
   CURSOR c_dual2 IS SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 1=2;
BEGIN
   OPEN c_dual1;

   IF c_dual1%NOTFOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('1 is not found');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('1 is found');
   END IF;

   CLOSE c_dual1;

   OPEN c_dual2;

   IF c_dual2%NOTFOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('2 is not found');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('2 is found');
   END IF;

   CLOSE c_dual2;

END;
```

Wrote this output:

```
1 is found
2 is found
```

But I expected this:

```
1 is found
2 is not found
```

Why, since cursor2 retrieves no rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't **fetch**. If you do (lines #7 and #17):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     CURSOR c_dual1 IS SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 1=1;
  3     CURSOR c_dual2 IS SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 1=2;
  4     l_dummy number;
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN c_dual1;
  7     fetch c_dual1 into l_dummy;
  8     IF c_dual1%NOTFOUND THEN
  9        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('1 is not found');
 10     ELSE
 11        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('1 is found');
 12     END IF;
 13
 14     CLOSE c_dual1;
 15
 16     OPEN c_dual2;
 17     fetch c_dual2 into l_dummy;
 18     IF c_dual2%NOTFOUND THEN
 19        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('2 is not found');
 20     ELSE
 21        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('2 is found');
 22     END IF;
 23
 24     CLOSE c_dual2;
 25
 26  END;
 27  /
1 is found
2 is not found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. Told you I was a noob. :-) I'll accept the answer as soon as the system permits.